# Polo 8 speeds up when releasing gas pedal instead of losing speed in second gear

Tags: vw, polo

I own a brand new Polo 8 and here's my problem : When i release my foot off the gas pedal hoping the car would lose speed especially in traffic , suddenly the car does the opposite and speeds up a bit so i come too close to the car in front of me and i have to break and even if i release the break it still speeds up and the only way to lose speed is when i press on the clutch pedal . What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: When you push the clutch pedal, what happens? Do the revs just start climbing higher and higher? Or another question, does this only happen for 1 or 2 seconds after you release the gas pedal, or does it just keep accelerating?

Comment: when i release the gas pedal it just keeps accelerating until i push the brakes or just simply push the clutch pedals and then the cars starts slowing down

Comment: Hmm that's strange. I was going to suggest rev hang, but this sounds more like a sticky throttle, except I don't think your car uses a throttle cable linkage. Not really sure what this is.